# QML ComboBox Popup Issue

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qcombobox

I have used so many combo boxes recently but there is an issue in the popup of a particular `ComboBox` which I am not able to find the exact problem following is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ComboBox{
        id:comboNum
        width:parent.width * 0.30
        height:parent.height * 0.15
        model: ["12","23","78","23","45","70"]
        currentIndex: 0

        popup: Popup{
            id:popup
            y: comboNum.height - 1
            width: comboNum.width
            height: comboNum.height * 2
            padding: 1

            contentItem: ListView {
                id: listview
                implicitHeight: popup.height
                clip: true
                model:comboNum.delegateModel
                currentIndex: comboNum.highlightedIndex
                interactive: true
                highlightMoveDuration: 0
                boundsBehavior: ListView.StopAtBounds

                ScrollBar.vertical:ScrollBar {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The popup doesn't show up all the elements and i am using QT 5.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [customisation docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox), I can see that it sets a model conditionally, based on whether or not the popup is visible. Doing the same for your snippet makes it work for me:

```
model: popup.visible ? comboNum.delegateModel : null
```

However, the [Default style implementation of `ComboBox`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/ComboBox.qml#n121) doesn't do that, so I'm not sure why it's necessary in your case.

Comment: Oh this is something weird. I never thought that this will be the issue. Will try to figure it out why should we do that !!! based on the visibility